# Statistical test for comparing directional data

Tags: anova, categorical-data, circular-statistics, rayleigh-distribution, von-mises-distribution

I have a dataset with number of bats flying out in 8 directions from their home site (i.e) I studied a bat colony with N individuals and I have counted the number of bats (from that colony) that flew out in 8 directions every night. By comparing the emergence proportions of different nights, I want to test if the colony has any directional preferences across seasons. This is a categorical data with each direction having a corresponding count/proportion of bats flying out per night. What would be the best statistical approach to do test this?

Comment: This sounds like a $\chi^2$ test.  Eight categories with a baseline probability for season 1 and you wish to test if season 2  distribution is the same.