# How to test the directionality trend and significance of a set of vectors?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis, trend, vector-fields

I calculated a directionality map, where at each point `(x,y)` I have a jackknife sample (n=8) of 2d vector displacements $\vec{D}_k$ ($k=1,...,8$ are the black vectors in the figure below; red vector -> "centroid" or average weighted by magnitude; magenta -> simple mean vector). The figure represents a single `(x,y)` position in the map.

[image: sample of vectors in black with the centroid vector in red and the mean vector in magenta]

**I want to know** if these **vectors** have a **"directionality trend"** and if this trend is **significant**.

For example: I could assume that if the sample vectors are (in average) pointing within a $\Delta\theta$ angle about the mean or centroid with `p<0.05`, then there is a trend and the mean direction is significant. $\Delta\theta$ is a free parameter, for example.

I have very little knowledge of statistics (although I have implemented t-tests before, and I understand correlation, covariance, and can calculate it in the context of Statistical Physics). So the more details the better (I'm using `MATLAB` for this project).

PS1: ChatGPT gave me many suggestions, although most of them didn't seem to directly apply here. One seemed useful: it suggested I could use the Wilcoxon signed rank test for each of the vectors' components separately; the nice thing is that it's implemented in matlab as `signrank`. The problem I see here is that this would compare to a zero median, and then it can only tell me if the trend is in one of the four quadrants relative to a median of the x or y coordinates of $\vec{D}$.

PS2: I thought of calculating the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the covariance matrix between the x and y coordinates of the $\vec{D}_k$ sample. It gives the ellipsis within which the vectors are... But then what?

PS3: I found these two similar questions, but none of them exactly matches my problem, nor they have solutions that would be directly applicable here:

- [Statistical test for comparing directional data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/514717/statistical-test-for-comparing-directional-data)
- [How to test if two sets of vectors are statistically different from each other](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223402/how-to-test-if-two-sets-of-vectors-are-statistically-different-from-each-other)